# Python init() error

Tags: initialization, arguments

```
class BankAccount:
  def __init__(self, deposit, withdraw, balance):
    self.balance = balance
    self.deposit = deposit
    self.withdraw = withdraw

    def balance(self):
      self.balance = balance

      def withdraw(self, amount):
        self.balance -= amount
        print 'self.balance'
        def deposit(self, amount):
          self.balance += amount
          print 'self.balance'

 a = BankAccount(90,40,1000)
 b = BankAccount(90,40,1000)
 a.deposit = 90
 b.deposit = 90
 b.withdraw = 40
 a.withdraw = 1000

class MinimumBalanceAccount(BankAccount):
  def __init__(self, minimum_balance=50):
    BankAccount.__init__(self)
    self.minimum_balance = minimum_balance

    def minimum_balance(self):
      self.minimum_balance = minimum_balance
      def withdraw(self, amount):
        if self.balance - amount < self.minimum_balance:
          print 'Sorry, minimum balance must be maintained.'
```

I'm trying to run the program but an internal error displays with the following syntax Internal Error:

```
THERE IS AN ERROR/BUG IN YOUR CODE
Results: 
Internal Error: runTests aborted: TestOutcomeEvent(handled=False, test=, result=, outcome='error', exc_info=(, TypeError('__init__() takes exactly 4 arguments (2 given)',), ), reason=None, expected=False, shortLabel=None, longLabel=None) is not JSON serializable
```

this is the question:

Create a class called BankAccount

```
Create a constructor that takes in an integer and assigns this to a `balance` property.
Create a method called `deposit` that takes in cash deposit amount and updates the balance accordingly.
Create a method called `withdraw` that takes in cash withdrawal amount and updates the balance accordingly. if amount is greater than balance return `"invalid transaction"`
Create a subclass MinimumBalanceAccount of the BankAccount class
```

this is the test code:

```
import unittest
class AccountBalanceTestCases(unittest.TestCase):
  def setUp(self):
    self.my_account = BankAccount(90)

  def test_balance(self):
    self.assertEqual(self.my_account.balance, 90, msg='Account Balance Invalid')

  def test_deposit(self):
    self.my_account.deposit(90)
    self.assertEqual(self.my_account.balance, 180, msg='Deposit method inaccurate')

  def test_withdraw(self):
    self.my_account.withdraw(40)
    self.assertEqual(self.my_account.balance, 50, msg='Withdraw method inaccurate')

  def test_invalid_operation(self):
    self.assertEqual(self.my_account.withdraw(1000), "invalid transaction", msg='Invalid transaction')

  def test_sub_class(self):
    self.assertTrue(issubclass(MinimumBalanceAccount, BankAccount), msg='No true subclass of BankAccount')
```

I don't know what is the cause.

Answer (score 0):

In AccountBalanceTestCases you are trying to instantiate BankAccount by passing one parameter (deposit=90). The `__init__` method on the other hand expects two more arguments, withdraw and balance.

This causes the following error during execution:

```
init() takes exactly 4 arguments (2 given)
```

It means that init received two arguments (the implicit 'self' plus the one you passed), but it actually expects 4. Try adding two more values to the construction, something like:

```
self.my_account = BankAccount(90, 100, 110)
```

This will get you past this error...